# unable to get webform submissions into our mail

Tags: webforms, emails

> I'm unable to get webform submissions data into my default mail,but
>   when submitting form i have received mail.getting below Body in my mail

Submitted on

Submitted by user:

Submitted values are:

The results of this submission may be viewed at:

Above name's comming from webform-mail.tpl.php file in webform module

```
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('Submitted on [submission:date:long]'). ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>

<?php if ($user->uid): ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('Submitted by user: [submission:user]') . ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('Submitted by anonymous user: [submission:ip-address]') . ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('Submitted values are') . ':' . ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>

[submission:values]

<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t('The results of this submission may be viewed at:') . ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : '') ?>

<?php print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : ''); ?>[submission:url]<?php print ($email['html'] ? '</p>' : ''); ?>
```

Please help me I'm new to drupal

Comment: [submission:date:long] is a token. So keep it outside php code.

Comment: Thanks @ Gokul N K
I have keep [submission:date:long] to outside php code no luck . values not coming so how can i debug whether the values are coming or not?

Comment: @GokulNK Its the default code of webfore template file. That is fine.

Comment: @Parvateesam Try to check your email settings under node/[nid]/webform/email. Also don't make any changes in module's template file.

Comment: I agree with @SumitMadan. Don't make updates to that modules file. If you want to custom the email AND want to do it from the template, clone that template into your theme/custom module and override it.

Comment: Thanks to all,i'm getting all submission values in debugging mode (print_r($submission); 
print_r($email);)) but i'm unable to view this values into mail this is my current problem ,i want to customize individual submission values with labels nice alignment but first i'm unable to print values please help me where it is wrong this is web form default functionality.is there any problem with tokens?, in email setting no tokens available

Comment: currently i'm getting below info into my mail:@Sumit Madan,

Submitted on %date
Submitted by anonymous user: [%ip_address]
Submitted values are:
%email_values

The results of this submission may be viewed at:
%submission_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have disabled all dependent modules for token and then disabled token module also again enabled all modules now working fine.